# can I use a number of "facebook likes" in php?

Tags: php, facebook

I am using facebook like in my site, and my php script need to know how many people like every page. For example I want to use in php `echo $likes;` where `$likes` is a number of likes.  Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

Using the new [Graph API](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/page) this is fairly straight forward.

Just do: https://graph.facebook.com/uniqueid/members

Using the new SDK library (http://github.com/facebook/php-sdk/) do the following:

```
$facebook = new Facebook($appId,$secret);
$facebook->api('uniqueid/members');
```

This should return a JSON array which you can iterate.